# Mostrar imagenes locales desde JSON en React

Tags: json, reactjs

pues como dice en la pregunta he estado tratando de mostrar una imagen local desde un archivo JSON, pero cuando uno va a inspeccionar el elemento se encuentra con `src="[object Module]"` y en la consola aparece un `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './/Jaspe.png'` y obviamente no muestra la imagen
He buscado como podría arreglarlo pero solo encuentro el de importar la imagen

Este es el codigo de donde se traen los datos

```
{
          thisdata.Materiales.map(slide=>
            <div key={slide.Material_id}>
              <img src={require(`../Assets/images/Home/${slide.picture}`)} alt="**" key={slide.Material_id} />
              <h1>{slide.Nombre} </h1>
              
            </div>
          )
}
```

Y este es un pedazo del JSON

```
 {
        "Material_id":"3",
        "picture":"Jaspe.png",
        "Nombre":"Jaspe"
 }
```

Tanto el nombre como el ID lo muestra bien, no se porque no mostrara ni la ruta de la imagen

Comment: puedes probar imprimiendo:

 <div key={slide. picture}>

y manda la estructura de arbol de tu proyecto, el ".." te sube 1 nivel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta el `.default` en el require, de todas formas yo lo haría mediante una función, asi:

```
const loadImage = imageName => (require(`../Assets/images/Home/${imageName}`).default);
```

Y donde quieras mostrar una imagen:

```
<img src={loadImage("image.jpg")} alt="img" />
```

En tu caso sería `loadImage(slide.picture)`